# Custom notification icon overwritten

Tags: android, basic4android

In the documentation it states to that a custom notification icon should be copied into the res/drawable folder. However I've noticed that every time I build the app the icon is deleted from the folder which in turn causes the app to fail. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: is file really deleted or it just gets removed from eclipse project setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the file to be read-only.